# How do I test the performance of my Wifi access point?

Tags: networking, wifi

I have a home wifi access point consisting of a small Intel board with Atom CPU, 4 GB of memory and a PCI wifi card. Everything works fine, only that I experience major lags during playing of computer games online. I am not entirely sure that it is the router's fault, but it seems to vanish after a reboot of the AP. During such lags, for up to 3 seconds, no packages are received by the game, while other services (like Teamspeak) keep working. It seems to be a single UDP (?) connection that hangs for some seconds. Also when I bypass the router and use the ethernet of my internet modem, the lags vanish as well.

Now, how could I find the root of the problem? The high traffic of the game seems to trouble the router so that it hangs sometimes and I don't know how to create artificial traffic conditions similar to the ones during gameplay.

On the AP, `hostapd` is used for the Wifi and the traffic is routed between the ethernet port and the Wifi clients. I basically followed this [tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Software_Access_Point) and set up a simple bridged network.

So in short: How can I test my Linux Wifi Access Point for high traffic and other heavy conditions?

Answer (score 2):

From your question: How can I test my Linux Wifi Access Point for high traffic and other heavy conditions?

There is a service which named **"chargen-stream"**, this service creates so heavy traffic. For testing your network you need 2 computers at least which one being server and chargen-stream lunch on it and you telnet to server (It's highly recommend to connect your server to your modem with cable not wifi), In this situation you transfer heavy traffic throw your router to the laptop. Here if your laptop crashed but your server not, It means there is a problem in wireless connectivity.

For installing chargen service, first you need to install **xinetd** and change disable parameter to **no** in **/etc/xinetd.d/chargen-stream**, and execute `service xinetd reload`.

Now telnet to server with port 19 :`telnet server-ip 19`

NOTE: For disconnecting from server press **ctrl-]** and write **quit** then **press Enter**.

There is another situation which you can start chargen service on your laptop and connect to it from your local loop back (127.0.0.1) it means `telnet 127.0.0.1 19` but the traffic doesn't travel from your router. Good for testing your laptop.

Comment: Hi, thank you for throwing in the chargen keyword. I will have a look at it later and report the results.

Comment: Your welcome, I hope it helps.